# Как дождаться с помощью Python полной загрузки страницы?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Есть список урлов, которые нужно обойти и собрать нужные элементы. Но иногда при проходе по этим урлам, некоторые из них как-будто не загружаются полностью и программа переходит к следующему урлу. Соответственно, нужные элементы не находятся, но они точно есть. Программа всегда по разному выполняется, иногда все ссылки открываются как надо, иногда рандомно с какой-то из них происходит такая ситуация. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить обязательное условие, проверяющее загрузилась ли полностью страница перед поиском нужного элемента?

Например код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\..\chromedriver.exe')
url = ['http://www.yandex.ru/', 'https://www.google.com/']
for i in url:
    driver.get(i)
    time.sleep(2)
    html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='content-all']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Задавайте явное ожидание элемента, например:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\..\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://ya.ru')
timeout = 5
try:
    # Вместо body возможно нужен другой тег указывать, характерный для сайта
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
```

Можно разные условия ожидания элемента ставить (например, `visibility_of_element_located`), смотрите в `expected_conditions as EC` и разные способы поиска, например по атрибуту `id`, смотрите в `By`:

```
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id'))
```

---

**2.** Можно задавать через `set_page_load_timeout`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\..\chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(0.1)              # 100 ms явно не хватит :)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
```

---

**3.** Специфичный способ через проверку в `js` ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30385843/5909792)) проверяя значение в [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).

Но это сгодится когда используется подзагрузка данных, например через ajax.

Думаю, будет примерно так:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\..\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(...)

timeout = 5

# Выполнение действий, затрагивающих подзагрузку, которая поменяет структуру страницы
# Например, пролистывание страницы
# driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete'
    )
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
```

Comment: По поводу 2 - не вижу смысла, ибо метод `driver.get` возвращает управление в код после полной загрузки страницы.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, согласен, неудачный пример :) Поменял

Comment: 2 способ не сработал, брал driver.set_page_load_timeout(15). По 1 способу вопрос: отредактировал код в вопросе. Если я ищу дальше `html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='content-all']").get_attribute("innerHTML")`, то как будет выглядеть первый способ в моем случае?

Comment: @gil9red подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: третий  вариант не сработал

Comment: @gil9red подскажите, пожалуйста, чем 1 вариант с явным ожиданием отличается от time.sleep() ?

Comment: @ChikChirik, явное ожидание задает максимальное время ожидания, но может и раньше выйти, когда условие в WebDriverWait сработает, например, вы можете указать там 30 секунд и столько скрипт прождет перед тем как выбросить исключение, однако, например, требуемый элемент через секунду уже подгрузился и ожидание завершится. А если вы укажите `time.sleep`, то это просто остановка потока на указанное время. Хотя в WebDriverWait тоже используется time.sleep: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d3b6ad006bd7dbee59f8539d81cee4f06bd81d64/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#L84

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, понял.

Comment: @gil9red, отредактировал код по 1 варианту, не сработало `timeout = 15 driver.get(i)
time.sleep(1)
 try: html = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'content-all'))
                        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(htm)
                        html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='content-all']").get_attribute("innerHTML")` не знаете в чем дело? может что-то не так отредактировал.

Comment: если ставлю time.sleep(5), то уже на всех страницах находятся нужные элементы, такой вариант и дольше и как-то не правильно по-моему. И сработал он без WebDriverWait